# Use Piccard iteration to find the solution of the ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A\in M_{n\times n} (\mathbb{R})$. Use Piccard iteration for $\dot x = Ax$, $x(0) = x_0$, to find the solution of this initial-value problem.

I know that the solution must be
$$ x = x_0 e^{At} = x_0 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(At)^k}{k!} $$
I started doing the partial integrals, but I have not been able to show the above. A friend of mine said that it could be shown by induction. Any hints suggestions or full answers to how this can be done?

The Piccard iteration is defined as follows
$$x_{n+1}=x_0+\int_0^t Ax_n\,\mathrm{d}t$$
By inserting we see that
$$x_1=x_0+\int_0^t Ax_0\,\mathrm{d}t=x_0+A\cdot tx_0$$
and
$$x_2=x_0+\int_0^t Ax_1\,ds=x_0+\int_0^tA(x_0+Atx_0)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
but by doing more of these, I do not see an obvious pattern and the integration gets messier and messier. Could anyone lend me a hand? =)

Comment: PiCCard? $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's continue :
\begin{align}
x_1&=x_0+\int_0^t A x_0\,\mathrm{d}t=\left(I+At\right) x_0\\ 
x_2&=x_0+\int_0^t A x_1\,ds=x_0+\int_0^tA((I+At) x_0)\,\mathrm{d}t=\left(I+A\frac t{1!}+A^2\frac{t^2}{2!}\right)x_0\\
\end{align}

So that you have indeed just to suppose that :

$$x_n=\left(I+A\frac t{1!}+A^2\frac{t^2}{2!}+\cdots +A^n\frac{t^n}{n!}\right)x_0$$
and deduce the $\ x_{n+1}$ term.